# how to use apex:inputField (lookup type) on public site

Tags: apex, force.com-sites

I want to use apex:inputField on public site. I have given read/edit permission on both object but when i on lookup, it open standard page as popup but say "Authorization Required".

Comment: Can you check for Guest User Profile has access ?Either there is an error or its a permission issue .

Comment: No, Its not a permission issue. When we click on lookup icon field, its open standard page as popup to select records. i think that page is not have permission for public site and we are not allowed to give permission on that page as it is not show in vf page list.

Comment: I fear then you will have to build custom lookup using Vf page using  Javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible,

1. Go To Develop > Sites
2. Click on Site Label
3. On the Details Screen scroll below to "Site Standard Pages" section.
4. Click Edit button and add "Lookup Page" to Selected Pages
5. Click Save

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is incorrect, this can be done without visualforce - simply go to the Site (Develop > Sites), drill down on your site and in the Site Standard Pages related list add "Lookup Page".